# Jenkins - This stage has no steps error Blue Ocean

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-blueocean

When this script runs, Jenkins reports that this stage has no steps. The lines of errors are the following:

Started by user administrator
java.lang.NullPointerException
Finished: FAILURE

This script ran without issue a few months ago and the script has not been changed.

I've confirmed that the folder referenced does indeed exist and has about twenty Typescript files (*.ts) in it as it did when it was last run.

```
    pipeline {
      agent any
      stages {
        stage('Change Service URL to Prod') {
          steps {        
            sh 'sed -i \'s/sddc-core-dev/sddc-core/g\' 
 /apps/ui/src/app/services/*.ts'
          }
        }

...
```

I would appreciate any thoughts or ideas on how to correct this. Thanks!

Comment: Try wrapping the `sh` script in double quotes instead of single quotes